# VBA Code for cell data language translation

Tags: vba, excel, language-translation

I'm writing a code to translate data from a selected cell from Portuguese to English, but I'm stuck with an error:

The translated cell is returning just "and" no matter what I write, it should translate all the words in a cell... Any ideas brilliant minds?

[image]

Here is my code:

```
Sub traducaobeta()

Dim translate As Object 'scritping.Dictionary

Set translate = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

translate("cadeira") = "chair"
translate("cadeiras") = "chairs"
translate("criado mudo") = "night stand"
translate("criado-mudo") = "night stand"
translate("mesa") = "table"
translate("mesas") = "tables"
translate(" e ") = " and "
' the list goes on...


Dim ptWords As String
Dim enWords As String

ptWords = LCase(activecell.Value)

For Each tempVar In translate.Keys()

enWords = Replace(Replace(CStr(tempVar), CStr(tempVar), translate(CStr(tempVar)), InStr(CStr(tempVar), CStr(tempVar))), " e ", " and ")

activecell.Offset(0, 1).Value = enWords

Next
End Sub
```

Anyone knows how to fix it?

Comment: change to `Dim ptWords As Variant`

Comment: Good!!! It worked :D But now it is translating everything to "and", I'm a newbie, could you help me to fix it? It should translate all the words in the active cell to the same active cell..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try a loop through the words in your text instead.
The following procedure translates every word that is found in your collection and leaves other words in portuguese:

```
Sub traducaobeta()

Dim translate As Object 'scritping.Dictionary

Set translate = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

translate("cadeira") = "chair"
translate("cadeiras") = "chairs"
translate("criado mudo") = "night stand"
translate("criado-mudo") = "night stand"
translate("mesa") = "table"
translate("mesas") = "tables"
translate(" e ") = " and "
' the list goes on...


Dim Words As Variant
Dim I As Integer
Words = Split(LCase(ActiveCell.Value))


For I = LBound(Words) To UBound(Words)
    If translate(Words(I)) <> "" Then Words(I) = translate(Words(I))
Next
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = Join(Words)

End Sub
```

Comment: I love you, did u know that??

Comment: Now just the cherry on da top of this sundae, just need the first word of the translated cell to be in Propercase (sorry for ma dumbness), do u know how do I do that?

Comment: I did this, but it makes all words go Capital, I just need the first word to go capital, look:

    For I = LBound(Words) To UBound(Words)
        If translate(Words(I)) <> "" Then Words(I) = translate(Words(I))
    Next
    activecell.Value = Join(Words)
        For Each x In activecell
        x.Value = Application.Proper(x.Value)
       Next
    activecell.Offset(0, 1).Select

End Sub

Comment: Just add `Words(LBound(Words)) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Proper(Words(LBound(Words)))` before you join the words again with `ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = Join(Words)`

Answer (score 1):

The error is telling you that you must use a `Variant` type variable in a `For Each` loop. You're using `ptWords` which is a `String` but the values returned from `translate.Keys()` are not explicit string types which causes an error.

Either declaring the variable as a variant

```
Dim ptWords As Variant
```

Or using a generic variant in your loop:

```
For Each tempVar In translate.Keys()

enWords = Replace(Replace(CStr(tempVar), CStr(tempVar), translate(CStr(tempVar)), InStr(CStr(tempVar), CStr(tempVar))), " e ", " and ")

activecell.Offset(0, 1).Value = enWords

Next
```

Should do the trick.

Note that I've explicitly cast `tempVar` to a string in the code using `CStr()` - whilst this may not *always* be necessary (due to implicit type conversion) it is a good practice to get into.